# Add a pointer/reference to service object property to a $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pointers

How do I add a pointer/reference to an object property (which is also an object) to the angular $scope?

Consider the following code:

```
videosModule.factory('VideoManager', ['YtVideos', function(YtVideos){ 
    return {
        videos: [{}, {}, {}],
        currentVideo: {},
        counter: 0,

        setCurrentVideo: function(){
            this.currentVideo = this.videos[this.counter];
        }
    };

}]);
```

And the controller:

```
videosModule.controller('SelectVideoCtrl', ['VideoManager', '$scope', function(VideoManager, $scope){

    $scope.currentVideo = VideoManager.currentVideo;

    $scope.videomanager = VideoManager;

}]);
```

Now I would like the first line in the controller to point to the property currentVideo, so that when this is changed in the service, it will be updated to the $scope.

This is not working, however when I reference the entire service (second line) and use {{ videomanager.currentVideo }} it does work.

Can someone explain this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.currentVideo = VideoManager.currentVideo;` is an affectation of your value. It means that it will never change. If you make this change, you have the second syntax : `$scope.videomanager = VideoManager;` which like the all factory. And then you can find the `currentVideo`.

But if you want something like the 1st syntax (and to avoid to use the wall factory object) you can use a function. A getter will be fine :

```
videosModule.factory('VideoManager', ['YtVideos', function(YtVideos){ 
  return {
    videos: [{}, {}, {}],
    currentVideo: {},
    counter: 0,

    setCurrentVideo: function(){
        this.currentVideo = this.videos[this.counter];
    },

    getCurrentVideo : function(){
        return this.currentVideo;
    }

  };
}]);
```

And then your controller will have to link this getter.

```
videosModule.controller('SelectVideoCtrl', ['VideoManager', '$scope', function(VideoManager, $scope){
    $scope.currentVideo = VideoManager.getCurrentVideo;
    $scope.videomanager = VideoManager;
}]);
```

Notice that there is no `()` in the controller. You will have to put them in yur DOM if you want the value to be refresh. Here it's just the function link. On your HTML, it will be something like this :

```
{{currentVideo()}}
```

Comment: This works, but only if I define the getter function in the controller. Like this: $scope.getCurrentVideo = function(){ return VideoManager.currentVideo }

Comment: The problem is that if you do $scope.currentVideo = VideoManager.getCurrentVideo; the "this" in the method will be referring to $scope when called as {{ currentVideo() }} instead of the service object.

Comment: Yeah it's a reference to your controller. But you controller is also map to your service. It's a double mapping. So In fact, currentVideo() will run the code of your service.

Comment: @joshHunger Moreover I'm 100% sure that you don't have to define a function, I use this syntax all the time `$scope.currentVideo = VideoManager.getCurrentVideo;`. Your var is'nt type, it can be a function without any problem.

Comment: Hi apédémak, Yes this is a valid syntax, however it is not a good solution for this situation. Please checkout this JSfiddle to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ZaphodBBX/HB7LU/16101/

Answer (score 0):

In your controller your are referencing to VideoManager.currentVideo to $scope.currentVideo

```
  $scope.currentVideo = VideoManager.currentVideo;
```

Which is fine, till you don't change reference of VideoManager.currentVideo. When you change currentVideo refernce in your service, VideoManger.currentVideo will be pointing to new reference but your $scope.currentVideo is still pointing to old reference.

If you use a object and modify its property, but for accessing that property you are using that object then it will work just fine. Same is happening with your following statement

```
$scope.videomanager = VideoManager;
```

In this you $scope.videomanager is pointing to your service VideoManager. You never change VideoManagaer reference. So $scope.videoManger will always point to same reference throughout your appplication. If you change any property of VideoManager, then it will reflect you controller because you are accessing it using service object.

Answer (score 0):

So, in angularjs, Service just are singletons and they are Lazily instantiated.

> Angular services are:
>
> Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an
> application component depends on it.
>
> Singletons
> – Each component
> dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance
> generated by the service factory.
>
> [Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

You can do it without any getter function, just by wrapping your service into your `$scope`.

In your example, `$scope.currentVideo = VideoManager.currentVideo;` just refers to the name of your video, it's **just a string**, not an object, **not your Service**.

But if you do `$scope.videomanager = VideoManager;`, you will wrap you service into your `$scope`. Then, when you will update a value in your service, the data in your scope will change because `$scope.videomanager` will be the entire **Service**, and the data will change in your scope, because your `$scope` is pointing to your **Service**.

So you can do :

**Controller**

```
videosModule.controller('SelectVideoCtrl', ['VideoManager', '$scope', function(VideoManager, $scope){

    $scope.videomanager = VideoManager;

}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div>{{videomanager.currentVideo}}<div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the good definition, but I was looking for a way to not have to point to the entire service in my scope, only the items I need (currentvideo).

Answer (score 0):

Angular only track those model changes which are done inside AngularJS’ context (i.e. the code that changes models is wrapped inside $apply()). Angular’s built-in directives and controllers already do this so that any model changes you make are reflected in the view. However, if you change any model outside of the Angular context (in this case service), then you need to inform Angular of the changes by calling $apply() manually. It’s like telling Angular that you are changing some models and it should fire the watchers so that your changes propagate properly.
When you use

```
$scope.currentVideo = VideoManager.currentVideo
```

Angular is not tracking VideoManager so the change inside VideoManager.setCurrentVideo method will not trigger model change.
But when you use

```
$scope.videomanager = VideoManager;
```

Angular is tracking VideoManager so the method VideoManager.setCurrentVideo is being executed inside $apply() which is built-in in the controller.

For example, the code below works but I don’t recommend it.

```
videosModule.factory('VideoManager', ['YtVideos', '$rootScope', function(YtVideos, $rootScope){ 
return {
    videos: [{}, {}, {}],
    currentVideo: {},
    counter: 0,

    setCurrentVideo: function(){
        this.currentVideo = this.videos[this.counter];
        $rootScope.$broadcast('scope.changed');
    }
};
}]);

videosModule.controller('SelectVideoCtrl', ['VideoManager', '$scope', function(VideoManager, $scope){
    $scope.$on('scope.changed', function () {
        if ($scope.apply) $scope.apply();
    });
    $scope.currentVideo = VideoManager.currentVideo;
}]);
```